# Pcloud api uploadtolink Error: "Invalid 'code' provided."

Tags: pcloud

Hi I try to upload to pcloud to one of my public folders.

If i try to access in Firefox: `https://api.pcloud.com/uploadtolink?code=CodeOfMyFolder` I get back:
`{ "result": 2012, "error": "Invalid 'code' provided." }`
I use the code from share link from pcloud: `https://e1.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=CodeOfMyFolder`

Answer (score 2):

Use https://eapi.pcloud.com/uploadtolink when you are in europe. Made the same misstake...